# Golang unmarshal struct with list of another struct

Tags: json, go

I am using Go and trying to unmarshal JSON to a struct which contains a list of another struct. Something is wrong where it doesn't unmarshal it and I cannot figure out why. Is there something else you are supposed to do?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type FullMessage struct {
    SubMessages []SubMessage `json:sub_messages`
}

type SubMessage struct {
    Value string `json:value`
}

func main() {
    responseBytes := []byte("{  \"sub_messages\":  [ {\"value\": \"testing\"  } ] }")
    myMessage := FullMessage{}
    unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(responseBytes, &myMessage)
    fmt.Println(unmarshalErr)
    fmt.Println(myMessage) // should be populated, but it isn't
    fmt.Println(len(myMessage.SubMessages)) // should be 1, is 0
}
```

Comment: You just have forgot quotes in tags. Should be `json:"sub_messages"` and `json:"value"`

Comment: Running `go vet` discovers this type of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes in the struct tag as follows:

```golang
type FullMessage struct {
    SubMessages []SubMessage `json:"sub_messages"`
}

type SubMessage struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```